# RSA Encryption using SwiftyRSA

Tags: swift, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm using SwiftyRSA for using RSA encryption in my app.
I'm receiving a public key in String format from server and I want to create my public key using that string but I can't achieve that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by 'create my public key using that string'. You can not assign yourself the same RSA public key as someone else - that is now how RSA works.

Comment: Well I don't know, backend guys are saying that.
What should I do?

Comment: It's just semantics, don't say 'my' public key, it's actually the server's public key that you will be using. 'Any help' questions, including this one, are often too broad for stackoverflow. As an aside, if you are doing client-to-server encryption you almost certainly should use TLS rather than some homegrown scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix this by creating the .pem file by using this string literal in swift """ for multiline string creation and it solved the problem.

Here is the example:

```
// This creates a multiline public key
fileprivate var pbKey = """
                        blah blah
                        blah blah
                        public key
                        """

// Then you use that public key in your pem file
let publicKey = try PublicKey(pemEncoded: pbKey)
let clear = try ClearMessage(string: "Clear Text", using: .utf8)
let encrypted = try clear.encrypted(with: publicKey, padding: .OAEP)
```